# Google Map full screen option disabled?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am using google map for my site but I can not see the full screen feauture on the map. How can I activate and why I can't see it?

**I have add following option to map:**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.coordinates[0][1], this.coordinates[0][0]),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                }
            });
```

**Here is my map:**
[image]

Comment: the width of the map is related with the div  that contain the map ... show the related  html and css code...

Comment: did you try this in your html code    <div id="googleMap" style="height:100%;width:100%" ></div>

Comment: #googleMap{

height: calc(100vh - 11em);

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the fullscreen control is not included on the desktop version of the Google Maps API. Add the `fullscreenControl: true` property to the object used to initialize the map. Your code should look like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
 zoom: 7,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.coordinates[0][1], this.coordinates[0][0]),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 zoomControl: true,
 scaleControl: true,
 fullscreenControl: true
 zoomControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
 }
});
```

Checkout the documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: strange, I still can't see something after I added fullscreenControl:true

Answer (score 2):

In the google maps documentation;

"The Fullscreen control offers the option to open the map in fullscreen mode. This control is enabled by default on desktop and mobile devices. **Note: iOS doesn't support the fullscreen feature. The fullscreen control is therefore not visible on iOS devices."**

This comment is a bit late, but maybe it helps someone.

The article link is; [Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?hl=nl)

The section is; Controls Overview

Comment: Could you link the article with the section you quoted?